# Angularjs : Why I need to click on a button to get my view updated?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to developpe a chrome extension with angularjs and I have a strange behaviour when I try to initialize the $scope with the url of the active tab.

Here the code of my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.service']);

app.controller('ItemCtrl', function ($scope, chromeHelper) {

    $scope.website = "No result!";

    // Does not work until I click on something :-/
    chromeHelper.getActiveTabDomain(function (domain) {$scope.website = domain; });

});
```

So when I try to initialize directly the $scope.website member it doesn't succeed but when I click on the button aftewards $scope.website then updates.

I really don't understand why.

Here is the code of my Chromehelper service:

```
var service = angular.module('app.service', []);

service.factory('chromeHelper', function() {
    var chromeHelper = {};

    chromeHelper.getActiveTabDomain = function (callback){
            chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function(tabs){
                if(tabs && tabs.length > 0) callback(getDomainFrom(tabs[0].url));
            });
        };

    return chromeHelper;
});

function getDomainFrom(url) {
    return url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: OK I solve my problem by calling $scope.$apply() at the end of the callback.

Comment: A cleaner way is to do it like this:$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.selectedItem.website = domain});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP solved the problem (see comment above) by adding `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the callback:

```
// Does not work until I click on something :-/
chromeHelper.getActiveTabDomain(function(domain) {
    $scope.website = domain;
    $scope.$apply();    // <-- adding this line did the trick
});
```

---

A short explanation for anyone landing on this page with a similar problem:

From the **[AngularJS docs on 'scope'](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)** (more specifically from the section titled '**[Scope Life Cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope/#what-are-scopes_scope-life-cycle)**'):

> **Model mutation**
>
> For mutations to be properly observed, you should make them only within the scope.$apply(). (Angular APIs do this implicitly, so no extra $apply call is needed when doing synchronous work in controllers, or asynchronous work with $http or $timeout services.

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/cj2eb/)**.